# On the Definition of the Reynolds Operator.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, invariant-theory

> Given an action of a finite group $\Gamma$ on a polynomial ring $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$, we define the Reynolds operator $R_\Gamma: {k}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]\to {k}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ by 
>   $$ R_\Gamma(f)=\frac{1}{\lvert \Gamma\rvert}\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma}\gamma\cdot f.$$
>   This operator satisfies some nice properties, in that it is ${k}-$linear, and it projects ${k}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ onto its ring of invariants under $\Gamma-$action: ${k}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]^\Gamma.$

My question is the following: how is $R_\Gamma$ defined for when ${k}\ne \mathbf{Q,R,C}$? That is, we could conceivably run into a scenario over $\mathbf{F}_p$ (or some other general field) where $\frac{1}{\lvert \Gamma\rvert}$ does not make any sense, and is not cancelled by a term of $\lvert \Gamma\rvert$ popping out of the sum.

Comment: It probably isn't. It's well-known that the representation theory of a finite group over a field of characteristic $p$ is much more complex when $p\mid|\Gamma|$.

Comment: If you wish to write your comment up as an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am writing an answer for this because otherwise I don't think it will ever get one.

As mentioned in the comment by Angina Seng, this definition of the Reynold's Operator only makes sense when the $\operatorname{char}(k)$ is zero or is coprime to the order of the group $\Gamma$.

In particular, in the course I was taking we interested ourselves mostly in the situation where $k=\mathbb{C}$ or a number field.