# Invariants of the Hyperoctahedral group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles, invariant-theory

Apologies in advance for what I am asking might be too trivial, I am not a mathematician.

I have a function $V(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ that **could** have, at most, a hyperoctahedral (signed permutations) symmetry given by $H = S_2^n \rtimes S_n$. For those who do not know, acting with a group element on a vector space element permutes the vector element indices and changes the signs of some elements.  I say that it can have at most this symmetry because $V$ might have fewer symmetries, i.e. be just a subgroup of the hyperoctahedral group.

My goal is to find this subgroup and to check whether two vector elements are the same under the subgroup.

To solve the first problem I generated all group elements $g$ and checked which group elements keep $V$ the same, i.e. $V(x_i) = V(g \cdot x_i)$. Is this the optimal way? Do I have to check all $2^n n!$ ($|H| = 2^n n!$) elements or would checking only the group generators be enough?

For the second part of my question I do not have yet have a clear answer. This is my attempt. Inspired by the elementary symmetric polynomials (example 1.4 of https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/rogora/pdf/Enrico.pdf). I defined a polynomial
$$
\phi(t):=\left(t-x_1^2\right)\left(t-x_2^2\right) \cdots\left(t-x_n^2\right)=t^n-\sigma_1 t^{n-1}+\sigma_2 t^{n-2}-\cdots+(-1)^n \sigma_n
$$
where the $\sigma_i$ are given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_1 & =x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2 \\
\sigma_2 & =x_1^2 x_2^2+x_1^2 x_3^2+\cdots+x_1^2 x_n^2+x_2^2 x_3^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2 x_n^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\sigma_r & =\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots i_r} x_{i_1}^2 x_{i_2}^2 \cdots x_{i_r}^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\sigma_n & =x_1^2 x_2^2 \cdots x_n^2
\end{aligned}
$$

It is obvious that this polynomial is invariant under H. Could I use $\sigma_i$ as invariants of $H$? If two elements $x,y\in V$ have the same $\sigma_i$, can I conclude that they are the same under the group symmetries, i.e. there exists a $h\in H$ such that $x = h\cdot y$?

Comment: To find H-invariants you could use the Reynolds operator https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478781/on-the-definition-of-the-reynolds-operator

Comment: @Leox Thank you for your answer. It seems that the Reynolds operator is not injective so it would not allow me to distinguish between elements.

Comment: Well, the operator is a surjective map into algebra of  H-invariants. There is no another tool to find generating element of algebra  of invariants for finite group. It seems that your case is quite simple and this problem can be  easily solved.